# How to get url of video element of an iframe using puppeteer

Tags: javascript, web-scraping, puppeteer

Good afternoon friend,

I am trying to be able to take the video from the url of the iframe, from what I see I have to first click the video so that the video element is visible in html.

Isn't there a way to automate the process?
Click automatically when entering the url and extract the url from the video

I'm supposed to get the following url from the video at the end

`https://fvs.io/redirector?token=aVVHRmZNVzZVdldkRXJUZXdrSWRQV2RxQ2RSSjdFNGphTVBVQTVBRTR4TlpFYXdMbzlXaktueW9ETW5ma2QvYjlOZG42Mzg2eGNWSDNjT3BHUC8wMmxyUTcrZyt4ZzRwV0s4UWVLcWQzZExzdUVBN1dIbUVmSVhrbnlIWENwWHhFR09LRVBHcXpLUmg4NFlCaW10SzBGeVU2VXVNL3FvMjpUMXRDKytHYng5S1RTTU1laG0vbFZRPT0`

**index.js**

```js
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');


const main = async() =>{
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch({headless: false}) 
  const page = await browser.newPage()

  await page.goto('https://feurl.com/v/2625zf2pddy2gew' , {waituntil: "networkidle0"})
  await page.waitFor(1000)

  await page.mainFrame().click();
  await browser.close()
}
```

Comment: is the video inside contents of iframe , or is iframe itself (iframe src points to video) ? also if the iframe is already in the page ... it doesn't have to be visible to access it so might not need to click on anything... btw i dont see any `fvs.io/redirector` in the link in your post

Comment: @hretic If you visit the url https://feurl.com/v/2625zf2pddy2gew of the iframe you will see that the video element is missing. First you have to play the video of the iframe, then if you go in the devtool you will see that the video element comes out

Comment: @hretic In itself, the url that I just mentioned is the iframe